# Silverlight designer unhandled exception (IOException) . Unable to open xaml page

Tags: silverlight

When I create a new Silverlight Application (C# if that matters) using Silverlight 4 and open the MainPage.xaml in the designer I receive an `Unhandled Exception has occurred`.

[image]

`Stack details` are as follows:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at MS.Internal.Platform.SilverlightPlatformImpl.Initialize()
   at MS.Internal.Package.VSIsolationProviderService.RemoteReferenceProxy.EnsurePlatformInitialized()
   at MS.Internal.Package.VSIsolationProviderService.RemoteReferenceProxy.EnsurePlatformInitialized()
   at MS.Internal.Package.VSIsolationProviderService.CreateIsolationProvider(String originalIdentifier, Boolean isGlobal, String identity, FrameworkName frameworkName, AssemblyName appAssemblyName, IVsHierarchy hierarchy)
   at MS.Internal.Package.VSIsolationProviderService.CreateIsolationProviderWorker(String identifier, IServiceProvider provider)
   at MS.Internal.Package.VSIsolationProviderService.CreateIsolationProvider(String identifier, IServiceProvider provider)
   at MS.Internal.Providers.VSDesignerContext.CreateIsolationProvider(IServiceProvider provider, IVsHierarchy hierarchy)
   at MS.Internal.Providers.VSDesignerContext.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Initialize>b__0(IsolationProviderProxy i)
   at MS.Internal.Providers.IsolationProviderProxy.get_RealProvider()
   at MS.Internal.Providers.IsolationProviderProxy.add_UnhandledException(UnhandledExceptionEventHandler value)
   at MS.Internal.Designer.DesignerPane.LoadDesignerView()
```

Please help to resolve this issue.

Comment: Have you changed anything in xaml? It means that you have error in your xaml. If nothing is wrong, then try to clean your solution.

Comment: I have changed nothing in xaml. I have tried cleaning of the solution as well, but nothing is working.

Comment: Show xaml code please

Comment: @AbhishekGahlout Pleasem show your xaml code.

Comment: I have nor changed anything in the default code that generated while creating new silverlight project.

<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">

    </Grid>
</UserControl>

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of brain storming googling and hit and trial , the things worked for me , after installing Visual Studio 2010 Service pack 1.